# How does Google handle "clean" URLs is the URL is always changing due to edits?

Tags: seo, google, search-engines, url-rewriting

So, since some "clean" URL system pull the wording directly from content I was wondering how Google handles this?

---

**Here's an example of content changes changing the URLs:**

---

**Version 1 of the Title:**

- [what-should-i-look-for-in-a-web-based-applicant-tracking-system](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4276/what-should-i-look-for-in-a-web-based-applicant-tracking-system)

**Version 2 of the Title, with Version 1 rerouting to this now, but V1 URL stays the same:**

- [what-should-i-be-looking-for-in-a-web-based-applicant-tracking-system](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4276/what-should-i-be-looking-for-in-a-web-based-applicant-tracking-system)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the URL keeps changing then as far as the search engines are concerned they are new pages and the old ones no longer exist. Once a page has been assigned a URL it should not change if the content changes *unless the content changes so much that the page URL no longer reflects what it is about*. In that case it is a new page and thus should have anew URL.

In Wordpress once you create a slug for a page it doesn't change even if you change the title of the post (I assume other CMSs work the same way). That's because once a page has been assigned a URL changing it only serves to confuse users and search engines alike. You wouldn't want people to change their names every time they change their clothes, would you?

Comment: **@John_Conde:** Well, that's not the way SE's site URL's appear to work. On SE, based on what I can tell, you change the title, and it changes the URL... but the old title is cached, and redirects to the new one. Have you seen this before, or am I confused?

Comment: **@John_Conde:** Added an example to the body of the question.

Comment: @John_Conde - WordPress actually supports 301 redirects when the slug changes.